# How to unlock all stages in Melee in dolphin 5.0?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee, dolphin-emulator

I enabled all the characters and stages using a gecko code. It gave me the characters, but not all of the stages.

Answer (score 1):

In Dolphin 5.0-14344, to unlock all stages in the USA or PAL versions of Super Smash Bros. Melee:

1. Open **Options > Configuration**.
2. In the **General** tab, check **Enable Cheats**.
3. Right-click **Super Smash Bros. Melee** in the gamelist and select **Properties**.
4. In the **Gecko Codes** tab, check **Unlock All Characters and Stages**.
5. Launch **Super Smash Bros. Melee**.

To answer your question specifically, I tested the "Unlock All Characters and Stages" Gecko Code in Dolphin 5.0-14344 on 4 different versions of Melee: USA 1.00, USA 1.01, USA 1.02, and PAL with empty save files and confirmed all stages were unlocked as expected. It's possible an older version of 5.0 may have had a bug preventing the cheat from working.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest simply downloading a file with the game complete. You can use the 20XX Hack Pack for this or by downloading a completed game file.